# Merging elastic search query and filter doesn't work correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I have to merge to query and filter. we did this in elastic search 2.4 using filter_mode(:must) after merging query and filter.

Now filter_mode and query_mode in incompatible. I am merging query using 'and'. I am using chewy for using elastic search in rails framework

```
query_string = index.query(bool: { should: [{ term: { title: query } }, { term: { tags: query } }] })

domain_filter = index.filter(term: { domain_id: domain_id })

merged_query = query_string.and(domain_filter)
```

now query_string product 1 result. so filter should produce a subset of that result.

instead when I do `query_string.filter(term: { domain_id: domain_id })`

It produces 44 results. My main goal is to merge both the query to filter results on domain_id. when i write domain_filter as query it produced a filterd result

```
domain_filter  = index.query(term: { domain_id: domain_id })


merged_query = query_string.and(domain_filter)
```

the above-merged query produces the correct result. but I think its wrong to use it like this. I want to use ES filter. can someone help me with this?

Detailed query
produced with query_string.and(domain_filter)

```
{:index=>["resource_domain"], :type=>["resource_domain"], :body=>{:query=>{:bool=>{:should=>[{:term=>{:title=>"club-4"}}, {:term=>{:tags=>"club-4"}}], :filter=>{:term=>{:domain_id=>6}}}}}}
```

the above one produces wrong result

Expected:

```
{:index=>["resource_domain"], :type=>["resource_domain"], :body=>{:query=>{:bool=>{:must=>[{:bool=>{:should=>[{:term=>{:title=>"club-4"}}, {:term=>{:tags=>"club-4"}}]}}, {:term=>{:domain_id=>6}}]}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shove your domain filter into a `bool/filter` clause, like this

```
query = index.query(bool: { minimum_should_match: 1, should: [{ term: { title: query } }, { term: { tags: query } }], filter: [{term: { domain_id: domain_id }}] })
```

Comment: it produced the same query but I want something like both should be merged with must clause. the above produces incorrect result in bool query

Comment: consider example like this 

scope = PlacesIndex.query(match: {name: 'Moscow'})
scope.query.and(match: {name: 'London'})

it produces result like this 
<PlacesIndex::Query {..., :body=>{:query=>{:bool=>{
      #       #      :must=>[{:match=>{:name=>"Moscow"}}, {:match=>{:name=>"London"}}]}}}}>

i need same kind of result for filter. merged with must

Comment: What used to be filters should now be merged into `bool/filter`, which is the same as `bool/must` but without scoring. Can you show the generated query and how it differs from what you expect?

Comment: updated my question with produced and expected query

Comment: Hmmm, my bad, you also need to add `minimum_should_match: 1`. See my updated answer.

Comment: it throws 400 bad request error ,my updated query is like this 
{:index=>["resource_domain"], :type=>["resource_domain"], :body=>{:query=>{:bool=>{:should=>[{:term=>{:title=>"club-4"}}, {:term=>{:tags=>"club-4"}}], :filter=>{:term=>{:domain_id=>6}}}, :minimum_should_match=>1}}}

Comment: error: 
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [VALUE_NUMBER]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"resource_domain_1514877919525","node":"zaN_Y-iCRmGzHrmqIIfpLw","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [VALUE_NUMBER]"}}]},"status":400}